# Repeatedly being stymied by missing packages using Texmaker

Tags: packages, installing, texmaker, ctan

Ok, so I started using Texmaker to make PDF files, and I am being repeatedly stymied by missing packages. (Windows 7 OS here).

Apparently, there is supposed to be a way for them to be downloaded automatically, but this does not seem to be the case for me. I have tried googling around for how to make it automatically add packages but I cannot seem to find anything, and the terminology is very, very confusing. Yes it is using MikTeX. Yes, I am using Texmaker.

Currently just adding the {mcode} package has become a full day project. Why is this so hard? How do I go about making Texmaker just download whatever package it needs?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`mcode` package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package) does not form part of any distribution and therefore requires manual installation. [Download `mcode`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package?download=true) and [put the `.sty` where TeX can find it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764) and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

All I can tell you is what worked for me using MikTeX on Windows 10.

1. I created a sub-directory on Dropbox C:\Users\MyUserName\Dropbox\LaTeX\localtexmf
   and created the following specifically named sub-directories under it:
   \tex\latex\local
2. I placed my mcode.sty inside the "local" sub-directory
3. On MiKTeX Settings->Directories I selected "+"
4. I then provided in the the requested field
   C:\Users\MyUserName\Dropbox\LaTeX\localtexmf